# Android how to play different sound for each item in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I build app with images of animals, and after you click on animal, its play sound for that animal.

I use Recyclerview for displaying all animals items.

My problem is that i do not know how to handle click event for playing sounds for each animal. I do know how to play same sound for each item in recyclerview but i do not know how to handle specific sound for each item.

this is code for my class where i handle data, where i put all animal names, images and sounds for each object.

```js
package com.example.android.animalsoundsforchildren;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Zivotinje {
    private String mAnimal_name;
    private int mAnimal_slika;
    private int mSound;


    public Zivotinje(String animalName, int slika, int sound) {
        this.setmAnimal_name(animalName);
        this.setmAnimal_slika(slika);
        this.setmSound(sound);
    }

    public String getmAnimal_name() {
        return mAnimal_name;
    }

    public void setmAnimal_name(String mAnimal_name) {
        this.mAnimal_name = mAnimal_name;
    }

    public int getmAnimal_slika() {
        return mAnimal_slika;
    }

    public void setmAnimal_slika(int mAnimal_slika) {
        this.mAnimal_slika = mAnimal_slika;
    }

    public int getmSound() {
        return mSound;
    }

    public void setmSound(int mSound) {
        this.mSound = mSound;
    }

    //putting data
    public static ArrayList<Zivotinje> createZivotinjeList() {
        ArrayList<Zivotinje> animals = new ArrayList<Zivotinje>();

        animals.add(new Zivotinje("Sheep", R.drawable.domestic_sheep, R.raw.gun));
        animals.add(new Zivotinje("Sparrow", R.drawable.birds_sparrow, R.raw.birds_sparrow));
        animals.add(new Zivotinje("Dolphin", R.drawable.sea_dolphin, R.raw.dolphin));
        animals.add(new Zivotinje("Bumblebee", R.drawable.insects_bumblebee, R.raw.bumblebee));
        animals.add(new Zivotinje("Tractor", R.drawable.cars_tractor, R.raw.tractor));
        animals.add(new Zivotinje("Baby Cry", R.drawable.laugh_baby_cry, R.raw.baby_cray));
        animals.add(new Zivotinje("Wind", R.drawable.nature_wind, R.raw.wind));
        animals.add(new Zivotinje("Golf", R.drawable.effects_golf, R.raw.golf));
        animals.add(new Zivotinje("Clock", R.drawable.others_clock, R.raw.clock));


        return animals;
    }
}
```

This is code for Adapter, and here i handle click and when i click on item, it play the same sound but how to play different sound for each animal, not the same sound like here. Here i always play sound R.raw.clock

```js
package com.example.android.animalsoundsforchildren;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class ZivotinjeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_zivotinje, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        Zivotinje zivotinjeIme = mZivotinje.get(position);

        // Set item views based on the data model
        TextView textView = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        textView.setText(zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_name());

        ImageView slika_source = viewHolder.imageView;
        slika_source.setImageResource(zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_slika());





    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mZivotinje.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView nameTextView;




        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zivotinjaIme_id);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.slika_id);





            //It works when i play for each item sound but how to play specific sound for each animal
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.clock);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private List<Zivotinje> mZivotinje;

    public ZivotinjeAdapter(List<Zivotinje> animals) {
        mZivotinje = animals;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want only image to be clickable or the list item to be clickable?

Comment: It is already list item clickable but this way its only play the same sound. I do not know how to achieve when i click specific item to play sound for that list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the link https://gist.github.com/grantland/cd70814fe4ac369e3e92

you can refer to the item click event and how to get the item on click  event

please refer the code below. i have made the changes

```
public class ZivotinjeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_zivotinje, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ZivotinjeAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        Zivotinje zivotinjeIme = mZivotinje.get(position);

        // Set item views based on the data model
        TextView textView = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        textView.setText(zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_name());

        ImageView slika_source = viewHolder.imageView;
        slika_source.setImageResource(zivotinjeIme.getmAnimal_slika());

       viewHolder.setItem(mZivotinje[position]);




    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mZivotinje.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView nameTextView;
        private Zivotinje mItem;





        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zivotinjaIme_id);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.slika_id);


 public void setItem(Zivotinje item) {
            mItem = item;

        }




            //It works when i play for each item sound but how to play specific sound for each animal
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                      // here you will get mItem and from that you can get the sound
                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.clock);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private List<Zivotinje> mZivotinje;

    public ZivotinjeAdapter(List<Zivotinje> animals) {
        mZivotinje = animals;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. THANK YOU.  I just needed to change   from viewHolder.setItem(mZivotinje[position]); to viewHolder.setItem(mZivotinje.get(position)); I will edit your answer later. Once again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use a switch statement that would check which animal is clicked and then act accordingly.

If you have a large collection of animals, make all the animals inherit from the Animal class which would have an abstract makeSound() method. Override that method in the subclasses to have them make their own sound. In the onClick() method, call the makeSound() method.

Comment: But in my app i want to have 200 animals, i can not do 200 switch statments.

Comment: thank you for helping me. I implement Mourice solution and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the position from ViewHolder by making a call to getAdapterPosition()

Once you have position you can get the item (animal object) at that position, something like by keeping a list of animals in your adapter. Now you can easily access the sound in the object to play.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, i implement Mourice solution and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

// u can implement the music on each position of recyclerview item by following

// in your adapter pass intent to the next activity where u are playing music in
bind view of your adapterclass

```
     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str_pos = String.valueOf(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("myKey", str_pos);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


 public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ImageButton buttonPlay;
 MediaPlayer mPlayer;

 AudioManager audioManager;
  boolean isPlaying = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    buttonPlay = findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    
   //getting the intent
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String tmp = extras.getString("myKey");
    int position = Integer.parseInt(tmp);

    //applying the condition on position of each
    if (position == 0)
    {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.r1);
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }

    else if (position == 1){
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.r2);
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }
    else if (position == 2){
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.mm);
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }
    else if (position == 3){
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.r2);
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }
    else if (position == 4){
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.mm);
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.isLooping();
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }
    else if (position == 5){
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.mm);
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }

    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isPlaying) {
                mPlayer.pause();
                buttonPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                isPlaying = false;
            }
            else {

                mPlayer.start();
                isPlaying = true;
                buttonPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            }
         }
    });

//perfoam on resume etc
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    stopPlayer();
    finish();
}

private void stopPlayer() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopPlayer();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mPlayer !=null){
        mPlayer.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mPlayer !=null){
        mPlayer.start();

    }
    else {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.mm);
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.isLooping();
        buttonPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
    }
}
```